# Core Data crash within a try catch block

Tags: ios, core-data

I have the following crash log and code to go along with it:

https://gist.github.com/emilevictor/7422ac293eb27b415fb8

I'm a bit confused, as I have wrapped this Core Data code (which creates a new instance in the database) with a try catch block but it is still crashing out occasionally in on release compiled code.

This is on a device which has had its local data wiped and installed from scratch, by the way.

I'm not sure what else to do, I assume that this code might have an issue.

Answer (score 2):

First the try/catch problem. `@try`/`@catch` only trap `NSException`s which have been `@throw`n or `-raise`d. You don't have this kind of exception, you have a [segfault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault). These happen at a much lower level and cannot be trapped in a `@try`/`@catch`.

The real problem here is what's going wrong to cause the segfault. Usually this is caused be objects which have been prematurely `-dealloc`ed or by notifications being sent to `-dealloc`ed observers. I can see from your call stack that the process is in the middle of sending a notification, so my guess it the second type.

Somewhere, you have registered an observer and that observer has gone out of scope (`-dealloc`ed) without unregistering itself. I would start by profiling the app for zombies.